# Uncaught RangeError: Wrong length! - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, electron

I am getting the error

> Uncaught RangeError: Wrong length!

and I can't figure out for the life of me why this is happening.

I initially had `File A` request File B and then by mistake also had `File B` requesting `File A`. I tried to fix the circular dependency problem and ended up just having `File B` request `File A`.

I thought that would solve all of my problems. However, when I go to `File A` to delete the line of code that initially requested `File B` and run my program I get the error. I can't understand why this is happening. Now, I just ran some tests, and see that File A just needs a require statement that requires a file, even if it is not File B. It is just needs a require statement, even if I do not use in that file what I am requesting. That makes this even more bizarre.

Any help is appreciated. I have already read a bunch of other questions with very similar questions, but no response to my problem.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Wrong length!
at validateArrayBufferArguments (core.js:5566)
at new ArrayBuffer (core.js:5656)
at VM181 zlib.js:334
at NativeModule.compile (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:287)
at NativeModule.compileForPublicLoader (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:222)
at loadNativeModule (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:23)
at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699)
at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717)
at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:853)
```

Comment: I am using AWS and its amazon-cognito-identity-js package and they require you to use require('cross-fetch/polyfill'). I realized that requiring the file that had that piece of code in multiple places was causing my issue.

Comment: hi, do you manage to solve your issue? can share with us ? tq...

Comment: Please, read my comment above. I had to re-structure my app and remove the require statement from multiple scripts.